# react-bootstrap Get current expanded Accordion

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have a custom AccordionHeader.

```
  const AccordionHeader = ({children, eventKey}) => {
    const decoratedOnClick = useAccordionToggle(eventKey, e => {
      console.log(e.currentTarget)
    })
    return <div className='accordion-header' onClick={decoratedOnClick}>{children} <img src={Arrow} alt=""
      className={'arrow'}/></div>
  }
```

I need to change the `img`'s  `Arrow` image if it's the accordian is expanded.
Something like this:

```
return <div className='accordion-header' onClick={decoratedOnClick}>{children} <img src={isSelected ? Arrow : ArrowUp} alt=""className={'arrow'}/></div>
```

The `onClick`'s callback, `e`, doesn't provide very useful information.

Is there anyway to get the currently selected accordion and the currently clicked eventKey.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `useState` in combination with `activeKey` in `Accordion`:

```
// Use state for the active key and set it to initial event key,
// e.g. '0' (must be a string)
const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState('0')

return (
  <Accordion activeKey={activeKey} onSelect={e => setActiveKey(e)}>
    <AccordionHeader>
      Your header content
    </AccordionHeader>
  </Accordion>
)
```

In your `img` you can then check like this:

```
<img src={activeKey === eventKey ? Arrow : ArrowUp} alt="" className={'arrow'}/>
```